# Creating static library from C++ code and linking with iPhone SDK

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, c, gcc

I have written some code in C++ with a corresponding C interface (i.e C-function wrappers around the classes) that a friend wants to use in an iPhone application.

Since I heard you can compile C++ for the plattform, but not use the iPhone sdk at the same time (sic) I thought that compiling all the code into a static library that my friend then can link together with his project in xcode.

So the question is,

What is, if possible the command line for compiling all my cpp files into a static library for the iPhone os?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode will happily compile C++ code along with C and Objective-C in a single iPhone project.